# Prevent bower from installing development files of momentjs

Tags: bower, momentjs

I have the following dependency listed in a bower-managed project:

```
"moment": "^2.13.0",
```

When I do `bower install --production` the result of `bower_components/moment` is 347 files weighing in at 6.5 MB.

I only need `min/moment-with-locales.min.js` from moment.

How can I tell `bower` to do so?